# SQL Query - selecting only 500 entries per ID in a multi ID query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 500
    n.NodeID as solarwinds_id,
    n.NodeName,
    n.Syslogs.MessageID,
    n.Syslogs.SysLogSeverity,
    n.Syslogs.Message,
    TOLOCAL(n.Syslogs.DateTime) as DateTime
FROM
    Orion.Nodes n
WHERE
    (n.Syslogs.DateTime > '2018-08-06 15:46:23.028792') AND n.NodeID IN (1845, 524, 38, 794, 35, 36)
ORDER BY
    n.Syslogs.DateTime DESC
```

However I quickly realised that I would only get the top 500 entries from the entire ordered date, i.e if ID 1845 had 500 entries I would only get that ID and no other.

is it possible to get 500 results per ID in a SQL query? (if there is 500 that is)

Thank you

Comment: Tag your question with the database ou are using.

Comment: sample data and out put.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT n.NodeID as solarwinds_id, n.NodeName, n.Syslogs.MessageID,
       n.Syslogs.SysLogSeverity, n.Syslogs.Message, TOLOCAL(n.Syslogs.DateTime) as DateTime
FROM (SELECT n.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n.NodeId ORDER BY n.Syslogs.DateTime DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Orion.Nodes n
      WHERE n.Syslogs.DateTime > '2018 15:46:23.028792' AND
            n.NodeID IN (1845, 524, 38, 794, 35, 36)
     ) n
WHERE seqnum <= 500
ORDER BY n.Syslogs.DateTime DESC;
```

Comment: I agree that `row_number` is a good solution, but shouldn't the `top 500` on the outer query go away? I don't think the OP wants to limit the entire result set to 500 records.

Answer (score 0):

Your current syntax suggest `SQL Server`, to get `500` results per `ID`  you need `row_number()` function :

```
SELECT n.NodeID as solarwinds_id, n.NodeName, n.Syslogs.MessageID,
       n.Syslogs.SysLogSeverity, n.Syslogs.Message, TOLOCAL(n.Syslogs.DateTime) as DateTime
FROM (SELECT n.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NodeId ORDER BY Syslogs.DateTime DESC) as seq
      FROM Orion.Nodes n
      WHERE Syslogs.DateTime > '2018 15:46:23.028792' AND
            NodeID IN (1845, 524, 38, 794, 35, 36)
     ) n
WHERE seq <= 500
ORDER BY n.Syslogs.DateTime DESC;
```

Comment: 400 Client Error: mismatched input '*' expecting 'Identifier' in Select clause, do I need to repeat the column names?

Comment: I put them in and now get no viable alternative at input 'OVER' in Select clause for url

Comment: so it turns out its not full ms-sql its Solarwinds sql. SWSQL or SWQL and im not sure it has some of the features in it needed for this query, are there any alternate methods you may know of?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Rank()](http://codingsight.com/methods-to-rank-rows-in-sql-server-rownumber-rank-denserank-and-ntile/) almost all db have this .

You can use CTE or temp table or sub query

Below is sample For CTE .

```
select * from ( SELECT 
    n.NodeID as solarwinds_id,
    n.NodeName,
    n.Syslogs.MessageID,
    n.Syslogs.SysLogSeverity,
    n.Syslogs.Message,
    TOLOCAL(n.Syslogs.DateTime) as DateTime,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY n.NodeID ORDER BY  n.Syslogs.DateTime DESC) as rnk FROM
    Orion.Nodes n WHERE
    (n.Syslogs.DateTime > '2018-08-06 15:46:23.028792') AND n.NodeID IN (1845, 524, 38, 794, 35, 36))

as a  where rnk <=500
```

Comment: so it turns out its not full ms-sql its Solarwinds sql. SWSQL or SWQL and im not sure it has some of the features in it needed for this query, are there any alternate methods you may know of?

Comment: now try the code .. assuming there is TOLOCAL() is a function in your db.

Comment: SolarWinds.Data.SWQL.SWQLSyntaxException: mismatched input 'with' expecting 'SELECT'

Comment: CTE is  not in the sql i have updated in sub query .

Comment: select * is not valid in swql so I put in the columns again, now I get  no viable alternative at input 'OVER' in Select clause. I think SWQL has a lot of missing features